# How to use provider in Errai IOC?

Tags: gwt, guice, errai

I have a problem with @IocProvider (), annotation does not work.
The code is very similar to https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/Container+Wiring

```
public interface Test {
    String getGreeting();
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class TestImpl implements Test {
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello:)";
    }
}

@IOCProvider
@Singleton
public class TestProvider implements Provider<Test> {
    @Override
    public Test get() {
        return new TestImpl();
    }
}
```

Then I want use DI in my broadcast service (errai-bus).

```
@Service
public class BroadcastService implements MessageCallback {
    @Inject
    Test test;

    @Inject
    MessageBus bus;

    @Inject
    public BroadcastService(MessageBus bus) {
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    public void callback(Message message) {


        MessageBuilder.createMessage()
                .toSubject("BroadcastReceiver")
                .with("BroadcastText", test.getGreeting()).errorsHandledBy(new ErrorCallback() {
            @Override
            public boolean error(Message message, Throwable throwable) {
                return true;
            }
        }).sendNowWith(bus);
    }
}
```

I get a error:

```
1) No implementation for com.gwtplatform.samples.basic.server.Test was bound.
  while locating com.gwtplatform.samples.basic.server.Test
    for field at com.gwtplatform.samples.basic.server.BroadcastService.test(BroadcastService.java:32)
  at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.ServiceProcessor$1.configure(ServiceProcessor.java:118)
```

If I change the code to

```
@Inject
TestImpl test;
```

It works, but I need the provider. Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're trying to use @IOCProvider in server-side code. Errai IOC is completely client-side.